# Как мне подготовить картинки для OCR с помощью OpenCV

Tags: java, android, python, opencv

Моя задача - прочитать промо-коды с крышек бутылок и коробок, крышки имеют разные цвета, а промо-код печатается по-разному. Я хочу подготовить текст с помощью OpenCV на Android и прочитать его с помощью тессеракта, подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли динамически обрабатывать разные картинки с помощью OpenCV (примеры ниже)? И как я могу выровнять текст с крышек бутылок в одну строку, чтобы, например, тессеракт мог качественно прочитать его? Спасибо.

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
**upd:**

[hsv_counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI93W.jpg)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

hsv_min = np.array((0, 77, 17), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((208, 255, 255), np.uint8)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fn = 'test.jpg'
    img = cv.imread(fn)
    img = cv.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)

    hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    thresh = cv.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max)
    contours0, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in contours0:
        if len(cnt) > 4:
            ellipse = cv.fitEllipse(cnt)
            cv.ellipse(img, ellipse, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv.imwrite("counter_cap.jpg", img)
    cv.imshow('contours', img)

    cv.waitKey()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[broken_text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIxGj.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("paper.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
src_gray = cv2.blur(gray, (3, 3))
canny_output = cv2.Canny(src_gray, 100, 100 * 2)

ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(canny_output, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
k = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, k)
closing = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(closing, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 3, 1)

k1 = np.ones((4, 4), np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(closing, k1, iterations=2)
small = cv2.resize(erosion, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)

# Write image
cv2.imwrite("erosion.jpg", small)

# Path
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

# Recognize text with tesseract for python
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("erosion.jpg")).replace(" ", "")
print("--------- TADAM ITS-------------")
print(result)

# Show image
cv2.imshow("erosion", small)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Качество Ваших изображений очень плохое.

Мне удалось хорошо подготовить только код с бумажки.
Вот, что у меня получилось:

[image: Пример кода]

Для того, чтобы получить это изображение я использовал OpenCV и взял маску по чёрному цвету.
Код на [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def get_mask(img, lower=np.array([0, 0, 0]), upper=np.array([255, 255, 255])):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    return cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)


def main():
    img = cv2.imread('photo2.jpg')
    crop_img = img[320:400, 350:930]
    mask_img = get_mask(crop_img, lower=np.array([0, 0, 130]))
    cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask_img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Привет, спасибо большое, с такой картинки у меня более менее получилось, самая главная проблема, как прочитать с крышки?

Comment: Я добавил в тему сообщения свои достижения... (